# GUI, Buttons not displaying in window

Tags: python, tkinter

For my homework, I have to create a widget. I'm very new to this. I'm trying to get my buttons to show up. I have tried packing them, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Here is what I have.

```
from tkinter import *
import turtle
main = Tk()
main.title("TurtleApp")

class turtleApp:

  def __init_(self):
    self.main = main
    self.step = 10
    self.turtle = turtle.Turtle()
    self.window = turtle.Screen()
    self.createDirectionPad

  def createDirectionPad(self):
    mainFrame = Frame(main)
    mainFrame.pack()
    button1 = Button(mainFrame,text = "left", fg="red")
    button2 = Button(mainFrame,text = "right", fg="red")
    button3 = Button(mainFrame,text = "up", fg="red")
    button4= Button(mainFrame,text = "down", fg="red")
    button1.pack()
    button2.pack()
    button3.pack()
    button4.pack()

main.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all your indentation is off, but once you fix that, you never actually create an instance of your `turtleApp` class, so none of that code ever gets executed leaving you with an empty GUI.

```
# Actually create a turtleApp instance which adds the buttons
app = turtleApp()

# Enter your main event loop
main.mainloop()
```

You also need to actually *call* `createDirectionPad` within `__init__` using explicit `()`. As it is, `self.createDirectionPad` (without the `()`) just creates a reference to the method and doesn't actually call it.

```
def __init__(self):
    # other stuff
    self.createDirectionPad()
```

**Update**

You also have a typo in your `__init__` function declaration. You are missing the final `_` in `__init__`

Comment: it's still not running after I create the instance

Comment: @Mia Updated above

Comment: I saw and fixed that after I posted the code. Apparently, there's another problem in my code that I'm not seeing.

Comment: @Mia Did you see my update about calling `createDirectionPad()` ?

Comment: @Mia What is `window`? that isn't defined.

Comment: it is supposed to be turtle.Screen()

Comment: Oh wow I didnt see that. Thank you so much. I have it running now

Comment: @Mia Consider marking this as a solution if it worked for you